# How to change from prisma to Cloud Firestore

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, prisma

So, I started a project using Prisma and it's already done. However, I need to change from Prisma (using a local SQL database) to Firestore (firebase noSQL database). How do I change the functions from prisma (like `prisma.tb_accounts.findMany()`) to FireStore. I searched the Firebase docs but they weren't explicit.

Comment: Going from SQL to NoSQL is a significant undertaking as the thought processes, coding constructs and data structures are totally different. If you have not done so, it would be advised to write some code using Firestore to get familiar with the product and SDK. You will then probably have a better idea of how to restructure data for NoSQL use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no migration tool that can help you move the data to Firestore. So if you're looking for a magic button that can convert your actual database to Cloud Firestore, please note that there isn't one. So if you need that, you'll have to convert the data in your database yourself.

Comment: Hey Tomás. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: It helped because it confirmed the idea I had in my head, but it would be better if there was a tool xD